# How to continue numbered list across sections in Mediawiki

Tags: css, header, mediawiki, indentation, numbered-list

I want to break up the numbered lists with section headers and the numbering to restart. Old Mediawiki formatting was like that, but with 1.24 it is no longer. For example

```
==First Header2==
#
#
==Second Header2==
#
```

Desired output:

> **First Header2**
>
> 1.
>
> 2.
>
> **Second Header2**
>
> 1.

Is there any css or extension I can use?

Comment: An example page of the site being asked about can be found at this link: [link] (http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachos_of_Sleep)

Comment: I copied the code of the page to a local test wiki and I can't reproduce the issue. Did you install any new addons recently?

Comment: I tried it on Wikipedia's sandbox page and didn't reproduce my issue. I nailed it down to extension:cite. When it is off, parsing works well. When there's footnotes, it gets messed up.

Comment: Note that the cite extension is enabled on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `<li value="X">`

Like this:

```
==Header==
# first item
# second item
==Another header==
# <li value="3"> third item </li> 
# fourth item
```

Comment: In the second part, it makes me a list headed by a 1. before the list... maybe a bug in my version: 1. 3. 4.